# docker-compose build yields 2 identic containers despite their Dockerfiles being different

Tags: flask, docker-compose, uwsgi

An attempt is being made to run 1 Nginx container and 2 uWSGI containers in order to serve two websites with a single docker-compose.yml file, but after the build both Python servers end up running the same command as opposed to what was written in their respective Dockerfiles. An explanation follows.

The directory structure is as follows:

```
.
├── app-aifriendly
│   ├── app.ini
│   ├── app.py
│   ├── Dockerfile
│   └── requirements.txt
├── app-bitcoin
│   ├── app.ini
│   ├── app.py
│   ├── Dockerfile
│   └── requirements-bitcoin.txt
├── app.conf
├── docker-compose.yml
└── Dockerfile-nginx
```

The docker-compose.yml file is as follows:

```
version: '2'

services:
  flask2bitcoin:
    image: webapp-flask
    build:
      context: ./app-bitcoin
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    ports:
      - "5001:5001"
    volumes:
      - "./app-bitcoin:/app-bitcoin"
    environment:
      - APP_NAME=flask2

  flask:
    image: webapp-flask
    build:
      context: ./app-aifriendly
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    ports:
      - "5000:5000"
    volumes:
      - "./app-aifriendly/:/app"
      - "./app-aifriendly/uploads:/uploads"
    environment:
      - FLASK_DEBUG=1
      - FLASK_ENV=development
      - APP_NAME=flask

  nginx:
    image: webapp-nginx
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: Dockerfile-nginx
    ports:
      - "80:80"
      - "443:443"
    volumes:
      - "./app.conf:/etc/nginx/conf.d/app.conf"
    depends_on:
      - flask


volumes:
    uploads:
```

And "app-aifriendly"s Dockerfile is the following:

```
# We simply inherit the Python 3 image. This image does
# not particularly care what OS runs underneath
FROM python:3.6

# Set an environment variable with the directory
# where we'll be running the app
ENV APP /app

# Create the directory and instruct Docker to operate
# from there from now on
RUN mkdir $APP
WORKDIR $APP

# Expose the port uWSGI will listen on
EXPOSE 5000

# Copy the requirements file in order to install
# Python dependencies
COPY . .

# Install Python dependencies
RUN pip3 install --upgrade pip
RUN pip3 install -r requirements.txt


# Finally, we run uWSGI with the ini file we
# created earlier
CMD [ "uwsgi", "--ini", "app.ini" ]
```

while "app-bitcoin"s Dockerfile is the following:

```
 # We simply inherit the Python 3 image. This image does
# not particularly care what OS runs underneath
FROM python:3.6

# Set an environment variable with the directory
# where we'll be running the app
ENV APP2 /app-bitcoin

# Create the directory and instruct Docker to operate
# from there from now on
RUN mkdir $APP2
WORKDIR $APP2

# Expose the port uWSGI will listen on
EXPOSE 5001

# Copy the requirements file in order to install
# Python dependencies
COPY . .

# Install Python dependencies
RUN pip3 install --upgrade pip
RUN pip3 install -r requirements-bitcoin.txt

# Finally, we run uWSGI with the ini file we
# created earlier
#CMD [ "uwsgi", "--ini", "app.ini" ]
CMD ["python3", "void.py"]
```

At the end of the day, running

```
docker-compose up -d
```

followed by

```
docker-compose ps
```

yields

```
aifriendly_flask2bitcoin_1   uwsgi --ini app.ini            Up       0.0.0.0:5000, 0.0.0.0:5001->5001/tcp                       
aifriendly_flask_1           uwsgi --ini app.ini            Up       0.0.0.0:5000->5000/tcp     
    
aifriendly_nginx_1           /docker-entrypoint.sh ngin     Up       0.0.0.0:443->443/tcp,      
                             ...                                     0.0.0.0:80->80/tcp
```

but according to "app-bitcoin"s Dockerfile the container called "aifriendly_flask2bitcoin_1" should be running

```
python void.py
```

---------------FURTHER INFO-----------------

running

```
docker exec -it 'container name' /bin/sh
```

shows that "app-aifriendly"s root contains a directory called "app", while "app-bitcoin"s root contains BOTH a directory called "app-bitcoin" (expected) and "app" (unexpected). In particular, both shells spawn inside the "app" directory, which leads me to believe that the orchestator is incorrectly configured.

Thank you for your time!

Answer (score 0):

They don't look to be the same, and if they are, are you sure that you're specifying different Dockerfiles?

Comment: They are not, and the specification can be seen in the question's docker-compose.yml file. In each, a different context is specified so that each container is related to the Dockerfile inside its respective directory.

Comment: In that case, the containers aren't the same unless they're doing something funky with their docker commands